# Newbie- Apply texture to specific area

Tags: texturing, materials

newbie here!!!

Uploaded face skin texture to place on character(xbot) but having a hard time applying the texture solely to the face. How do I attach the texture to a specific part of the body?

Thank ya :)

Comment: Thank soo very much...this helps alot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a material, just select in Edit-Mode all vertices you want to have that texture like this:

[image]

Then tap on "Assign".

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank soo very much...this helps alot :)

Comment: glad i could help. If my answer helped you, please check the checkmark left to my answer. Thank you and happy blending!